# Inverse Trig Functions Composite functions of Csc, Sec, And Cot

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

Ok guys.. I'm trying to get prepared for my test tomorrow and I did numerous exercises. But I stumbled upon one of the "types" of exercises. Which is a composite function in $\csc$ and $\sec$. For example, it would give you this:

1. $\csc\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right]$
2. $\sec\left[\sin^{-1}\left(-\dfrac{2}{5}\right)\right]$

So those types of questions I need to understand more on. Help would be very much appreciated!(Try to relate to Unit Circle Please..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that $\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ must be in the first quadrant so any other trigonometric calculations must be positive.

You then have two possible approaches:

**Option 1**

Let $x=\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ so you have that $\cos x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Draw the triangle:

[image]

Calculate the length of the other side (using Pythagoras), it is of length 1.

Then calculate $\csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}=2$

**Option 2**

Note that we are trying to evaluate $\csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}$

Let $x=\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ so you have that $\cos x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Use $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ to get: $\sin x = \sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{1-\frac34}=\sqrt{\frac14}=\frac12$

Evalute $\csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{\frac12}=2$

**Comparison of Options**

Both use the same underlying calculation. The first is easier numerically/algebraically but requires you to draw a diagram and remember all your ratios correctly. The second requires stronger algebraic skills and remembering that $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$ as well as which reciprocal functions are which.

Comment: Ok ill check on this. Thanks Ian Miller

Comment: Ian can you do it using trig functions? And could you do this: sec[sin−1(−25)] ... Instead of the cos one. Here is about inverse trig functions:  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/AlgebraTrigReview/InverseTrig.aspx +1 for trying though. But it would be AWESOME If you could put it on this formar

Comment: It was done using trig functions. What you mean by "using trig functions"? The second question would be basically the same as the first one but just with different numbers in places.

Comment: I mean like... I want unit circle concepts to pop up there. Because in our class we are learned about Unit Circle. And it will have to involve using unit circle logic.

Comment: It uses $\cos$, $\sin$ and the facts that $\csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}$ and $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$. They are all unit circle concepts.

Comment: Yes i understand the sin2. But we arent suppose to use that. Oh well ima try to do this on my own. But Ian i really do appreciate you trying to help. Im Not sure if im suppose to mark accepted, but ill do it for your time. Again Thankyou

Comment: Amanuel, you must have misunderstood your teacher because it simply doesn't make sense to not allow you to use this,is is the most basic and crucial properties that are being used

Comment: @AmanuelBogale The Unit Circle as a concept is an extension of the trigonometry you learnt in previous years where Sin was $\frac{opposite}{hypotenus}$. All these past things still apply. What the Unit Circle lets us do is extend those ideas beyond the range $0^\circ$ to $90^\circ$.

Comment: If you can be specific about what you/your teacher expects you to use/not use then we can tailor an answer to that but as I and others have said not using those ideas doesn't make much sense as they are all interrelated. I'm also concerned if your teacher isn't encouraging you to use prior knowledge so that you can build up the links that exist within different branches of mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

edited to make more clear

If you can do one of these problems you can do any of them, for example let us do your second problem.  The key here is that the inverse trig on the inside gives you an ANGLE. If that angle happens to be in the first quadrant, (which it will be in all of these types of problems) then we can easily compute the value using right triangles.

set $\theta = \sin^{-1}{2/5}$

Draw a right triangle with the angle $\theta$ in it, then by the definition of the angle $\theta$ we have $\sin(\theta) = \frac{2}{5}$. Now the definition of $sin$ in a right triangle is opposite side over adjacent side. So set the side opposite $\theta$ to 2 and the hypotenuse to 5. Use the Pythagorean theorem to find the 3rd side.  Now the secant of $\theta$ is by definition the ratio of the hypotenuse over adjacent

Comment: We are absolutely not talking about pytahgoren here.. In My class we are talking about unit circle. So try to relate to unit circle please

Comment: You can not separate the Pythagorean theorem from trigonometry, It is at the heart of virtually every property you have ever learned about trig functions. It is built into the equation of the unit circle, $x^2+y^2 = 1$